# Select HTML content

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to locate an element and grab an entire block of HTML.

I tried this:

```
$(this).find('h1').html();
```

But only was able to capture the text withing h1 tag... What am I missing?

Comment: just detect the tag of the _block of HTML_ and ask jQuery to find _that_ instead of _h1_;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's [a simple plugin](http://boedesign.com/blog/2011/03/31/outerhtml-plugin-for-jquery/). Use it as follows:

```
$(this).find('h1').outerHtml();
```

---

If you don't want to depend on the plugin, here's a solution with less code, but not as efficient:

```
var html = $('<div />').html( $(this).find('h1').clone() ).html();
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nxfTf/

Comment: I'm trying to write my own plug-in, so I can't really reference another one. But thanks for the suggestion -- looks great.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this.

```
$(this).find('h1')[0].outerHTML
```

I did this fiddle, if you need something a little more visual: http://jsfiddle.net/aPGGS/

Comment: Firefox 10 and under do not support this, so I'd shy away from using this directly...

Comment: Meh... I should have tried it on older browser too. Thanks for the heads up.